# Find my block chain

Tags: lost-bitcoins

How can I find all of my lost bitcoin accounts and transfer the funds? I was just recently made aware that there are multiple Bitcoin accounts in my name and a block chain. I don't know where to go from there to locate the accounts and transfer the funds so I can gain access to my cash.

Comment: How were you made aware of this? There are many scams that use such tactics to fain access to your details.

Comment: I should clarify. It's more along the lines of perception. Whether or not my perception is correct is an entirely different subject but I would like to find out before I discount the validity of said perception.

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin accounts are not linked to names, per se. There is not really a way where you can sign up for a bitcoin account under so-and-so's name, unless you go through an exchange such as coinbase.

There are basically two scenarios here:

If you are receiving messages/emails telling you to claim BTC, you are likely being scammed. Scammers send such messages out to try and get you to log into various sites, and steal credentials. Even if you genuinely do hold BTC on a site they tell you to log into, never click on the links in the email/message. Instead, open the site yourself, and log in to verify, and preferably change your password immediately (and set up 2fa if you can).

The alternate is that you genuinely did have BTC some time ago, but simply forgot where. Here, there are two options:

1. You were using an exchange such as Coinbase, Mt. Gox, Bitstamp, etc. or a hosted wallet such as blockchain.info (now blockchain.com). If this was the case, you will be able to find some trail in your email.
2. You used a regular wallet such as Armory, MultiBit, Bitcoin Core, Electrum, etc. In this case, the only possible way to recover any BTC would be to either find the wallet backup words (if it is a relatively recent wallet), or the actual wallet data file from whichever machine it may have resided on.

If neither of these two apply, you either never had BTC, or have lost it permanently.